# Can I select the "Video" post format and have video appear at the bottom of the post?

Tags: wordpress

Below is the code for [this](https://www.leonidhurwicz.org/2020/07/16/testing-video/) WordPress post:

```
If I select the "video" post format, the video appears above this text.

    <img src="https://www.leonidhurwicz.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/wp_page_formats-300x224.png" alt="" width="300" height="224" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-3443" />

https://irthlingz.com/bluekazoo_video01a.mp4
```

If I select the "Standard" post format, the video appears at the bottom, below the text and image.  If I select the "Video" post format,  it appears at the top, above the text.  Is there any way to select the "Video" post format and have the video appear at the bottom?

Comment: The page elements are displayed by the code in your theme files, so this is most likely to so with the template code that is generating the display for your posts. However without seeing the code and having no specific information about your set up, it is impossible for us to tell what is happening.

Comment: Thank you @FluffyKitten.  I'm using the Divi theme.  I'll try asking on the Divi forum.

Comment: If you use a commercial theme that's probably the best thing to, do as they will have more specific knowledge about it :)